# How to print pdf from my Android app with Brother HL-1110 Series Printer

Tags: android, pdf, printing, usb, usb-otg

I check Brother Printer's Developer site and they provide SDK without support of Ink-jet and Laser printer. But another app "StarPrint" can print on this printer but it too slow process and sometime This app cannot print any thing in brother printer. I am looking for a better solution which can print PDF directly from my app using Brother  HL-1110 Series Printer.

Please help me with your valuable suggestion. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just had the same question.

Printer (here HL-1110) connected how ? Own WiFi or via Windows or Ubuntu (here 16.04) via USB. Installed and shared open for internal Network.

Problem under Ubuntu, there are after Installation two Printer
* HL-1110, use the USB, but dont print
* HL-1110 series, using brother driver and can print from PC good

Android:
I used install the App "PrinterShare, as less MB using", after starting, search WiFi search (or choose what you use) and I saw directly the HL-1110. Test Page goes into that Que, but as before cant print,

I have to manually move the job to the KL-1110 series, then OK.
Advantage by this "mistake", I can check the jobs before the printer gets crazy.

Happy to get other solutions may be more better. Problem, when choose brother driver, the 1110 series not there, so I took "generic" driver, works.